# RemotePresentitySubscriptionTarget error

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I am using the following code

```
RemotePresentitySubscriptionTarget target = new RemotePresentitySubscriptionTarget("sip:abc@gmail.com");
```

to get the presence of users but getting an exception as

> Invalid Uri: parsing error; suspect character: '%'.

How to pass the uri for this?in which format?

Comment: What version of UCMA are you using?

Comment: Is there any dependencies that prevents to use newer version of UCMA, like version 4.0 or 5.0 ?

Comment: The SipUri format is correct. "sip:abc@gmail.com" - I use Remote Presentity Subscription a lot in a Windows Service program. But I use UCMA version 4